# Replate Input Submit Types with a href - jquery usage?

Tags: jquery, forms

For all submits of all forms of a given site, I would like them to be replaced by a href links. The "a submit button" is done by applying a sprite technique.

So, something around those lines:

```
#formLogin .submit
    {
        width:60px;
        background:url('../img/botaoLogin.png') no-repeat;
        height:22px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-top:3px;
        text-indent: -9999px;
        display:block;
        float:right;
        background-position: 0px 0;
    }

#formLogin .submit {
    outline: none; /*atenção acessibilidade @todo onfocus necessário! */
}
#formLogin .submit:hover {
        background-position: 0px -22px;
    }

#formLogin .submit:active {
        background-position: 0px -45px;
}
```

On the HTML side of things, however, I would like to preserve the submit buttons for those that have javascript disabled.

```
<input type="submit" value="login"/>
<a href="javascript:document.forms['login'].submit()">Login</a>
```

I suppose that using jquery to .hide() the inputs of type submit and show the a with a class of submit, will work.

**But if we have 4 forms with 4 "submit buttons" with different names, should I do one script for each?**

I was hoping to have some help about sketching a javascript code that could be put on a "footer" of all my site pages that would replace the input types submits by anchors with a class .submitSomething, where something could be "login" or "register" (because each of those will have a specific image for sake of the sprite technique).

Hope I was clear enough. If not, please, let me know.

Thanks a lot in advance,
MEM

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't see a reason why you would replace submit buttons with a href links, since you can style submit buttons with sprites and everything just like you would any other html element, but anyways, you're concerned about such functionality with several forms. So here's the answer: you can use [jQuery.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) to submit the correct form. Here's a draft:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('form input[type=submit]').replaceWith('<a href="#" class="submit-link">Submit</a>');
    jQuery('.submit-link').click(function() {
        jQuery(this).parent('form').submit();
    });
});
```

Haven't tested the code, but it should work (maybe with a few tweaks).

Cheers.

Comment: quoting: "Well, I don't see a reason why you would replace submit buttons with a href links, since you can style submit buttons with sprites and everything just like you would any other html element" - Can I style the "hover", and the "active" on a submit button? If so, please tell me how can that be done. I have no particular interest on a tag replacement, other then to be able to style those states as well. Thanks a lot again. Ps- please note that I'm aware that we can change AT SOME EXTENSION the over state of a input type submit BUT, not completely right?

Comment: @MEM, `input[type=submit]:hover` in your CSS would do the trick for most browsers. Not sure about IE though, I guess some old versions allow `:hover` only on `a` elements. Can't check, since I have no IE on my Linux box ;)

Comment: Yes but the active will not be the case, so the effect will be loss. Hence, the reason for having a need. Cheers for your linux box; (same here) ;) - Please be patience, I will need to have a look into your code later on and see what I get, but it will not be that soon. K. Regards. :)

Answer (score 0):

No. You dont have to write 4 different javascript.

If you use the [submit selector](http://api.jquery.com/submit-selector/) sintax you can just target your script to all of your input type submit elements.